# OpenCL slow memory access in for loop

Tags: memory, opencl

I have a program that I built in OpenCL, in which each kernel accesses a read-only buffer located in global memory. At some point each kernel needs to copy some data from global memory into a temporary buffer. I made a for loop to copy a region of global memory byte-by-byte into the temporary buffer. I execute the aforementioned kernel using the `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel` command which is located inside a while loop. In order to measure how fast the `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel` command is, I added a counter called `ups` (Updates Per Second) which is incremented at the end of each while loop. Every one second I print the value of the counter and set it to zero.

I noticed that my program was running slowly, at about 53 ups. After some investigation I found out that the problem was the memory copying loop that was described above. This is the code:

```
typedef uchar byte;

byte tempBuffer[128]

byte* destPtr = (byte*)&tempBuffer0];
__global const byte* srcPtr = (__global const byte*)globalMemPtr;

for(size_t k = 0; k < regionSize; ++k)
{
    destPtr[k] = srcPtr[k];
}
```

In variable `globalMemPtr` is a pointer to the region of global memory that needs to be copied into the temporary buffer, and `tempBuffer` the temporary buffer. The variable `regionSize` holds the size of the region to be copied in bytes. In this case its value is 12.

What I noticed was that if I replace `regionSize` with `12`, the kernel runs much faster, at about 90 ups. My assumption is that the OpenCL compiler can optimize the for loop to copy memory much faster when `12` is used, but it can't when `regionSize` is used.

Does anyone know what is happening? Can any one help me?

Comment: Maybe the compiler uses vector types instead of scalar types, e.g. 12 bytes = 3 * char4 = char8 + char4. Try to copy as much as possible as vector values and only copy the remainder as scalar values. Does this improve the running time?

Comment: @Harry Yes, it does improve performance. The program is running at 85 ups. Thanks!

Comment: It can also be using too many registers (128) per thread. Why don't you try using 64 group size and 128 sized parts per thread on __local memory is 8kB where max __local size is usually minimum of 64kB. When you use 12, it is maybe using only 12 registers but when its unknown it uses 128 registers.